# Is there hardware and/or software to spoof a controller for Xbox 360

Tags: controller, firmware, xbox

I want to create a controller for my xbox 360. Ideally I would like to create a racing wheel to play forza with, because, unfortunately, as any avid racing gamer with a 360 knows, the wheel market for xbox sucks.

Is there somebody who has reverse engineered a 360 controller enough to guide me in understanding how to make my own controller? What hardware limitations are there. Is the controller signal system spoofable with a custom designed controller hardware?

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with the hardware aspect, but have you heard of motioninjoy? It "spoofs" an Xbox 360 controller. My friends and I use it when we only have PS3 controllers lying around and we wanna play an emulator that only takes 360 controllers.

Theoretically, if the OS detects whatever you plug in as a controller, motioninjoy should pick it up too. At that point you just set it up to emulate a 360 controller. However if you're looking to write your own drivers so the controller can run without motioninjoy, I have no idea. If it's open source, maybe the code will get you on the right path:

http://www.motioninjoy.com/wiki/en/help